# Strange output from celery worker

Tags: python, task, celery

I have a celery worker that is kicking off a long task (the code that does the task is correct because when I run without a celery worker it works as expected).  But because I don't want to wait for it, I created a wrapper to go around my task that calls the function inside a celery task.  However when it's running I get some very strange output in my celery worker window (I won't paste it all but it ends like this):

```
00=\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00tbe]q<(h\x08h\tK\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq=(K\x01K\x01\x85h\x0c\x89]q>h\x0fatN\x85\x86bh\x08h\tK\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq?(K\x01K\x01\x85h\x0c\x89]q@h7atN\x85\x86be\x87bbu.', datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 12, 14, 18, 7, 234525), None, 16L)
```

The actual output is SIGINIFICANTLY longer but I wasn't going to paste it all here.  I know this is a generic question but has anyone seen any output like this?  Additionally the task never changes status and is always listed as `PENDING`

**EDIT**  If I run my task in verbose, I see the output I should expect from my task up until the end until it spits out all that crap.  Because my task works fine when I just run in sequence I have a hard time believing this is caused by my code (unless there is a special way to return dictionaries that I'm not aware of)

**EDIT 2**  So I found a solution to my problem but I can't explain this behavior.  Any insight would be appreciated.  I had something similar to the following in the celery worker

```
@celery.task
def celery_run():
    return task_run()
```

I was able to verify that the task was running fine and giving the right output and that the `return` statement was causing the problem.  However I only needed some aspects of the result so I changed to the following

```
@celery.task
def celery_run():
    results = task_run()
    needed_stuff = results['stuff']
    return needed_stuff
```

And now it works fine, and I'm not exactly sure why.  Is there a limitation on celery returns (data, formatting, etc.) that I should be aware of?

Comment: that is not strange at all, it is the output which you get when the text is in some non-english language. Ask me, i have a web crawler in python and when it crawls pages from wikipedia, i get this similar output when i get it from non-english pages..

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi But where would that text be coming from?  My code doesn't produce it...and that doesn't explain why celery says that the task is always in a `PENDING` state